# NaiveBays() is not working properly - Error in table(y, var) : all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r

I am trying to implement classifier algorithm using naivebays classifier. However getting an error -

Error in table(y, var) : all arguments must have the same length

while using command

> sms_classifier <- naiveBayes(sms_train, sms_raw_train$type)

List of commands executed so far -

```
sms_dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus_clean)
sms_dtm_train <- sms_dtm[1:39,]
sms_dtm_test <- sms_dtm[40:59,]
sms_corpus_train <- corpus_clean[1:39]
sms_corpus_test <- corpus_clean[40:59]
table(sms_raw$type)
table(sms_raw_train$type)
table(sms_raw_test$type)
sms_dict <- Dictionary(findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train,5))
sms_train <- TermDocumentMatrix(sms_corpus_train, control = list(minDocFreq=5,minWordLength=1))
str(sms_train)
sms_test <- TermDocumentMatrix(sms_corpus_test, control = list(minDocFreq=5,minWordLength=1))
convert_count <- function(x){
x <- ifelse(x>0,1,0)
x <- factor(x, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("No","Yes"))
return(x)
}
sms_train <- apply(sms_train,MARGIN = 2, convert_count)
sms_test <- apply(sms_test, MARGIN = 2, convert_count)
library(e1071)
sms_classifier <- naiveBayes(sms_train, sms_raw_train$type)
```

Regards
Amit

Comment: What is "corpus_clean"? It is perhaps better to clear the environment and then check, if the script contains all what is necessary to reproduce the example.

Comment: corpus_clean is an object contains cleaned data

Comment: sms_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sms_raw$text))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus,tolower)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
corpus_Clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean,stopwords())
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean,stopwords())
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean,removeWords,stopwords())
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean,removePunctuation)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)